# Show Hide input inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

HTML:
This code snippet is within an 'ng-repeat' block with let's say 10 elements. when I click on the 'span' I want to show and hide 'input' for the elements individually.

```
                                <span class="cs-p" ng-click="$ctrl.toogleRange($event)">
                                    <img ng-if="layer.IsSelected && layer.layers.length ===0"
                                        src="./assets/img/icons/map_controls/zoom_selected.png"
                                        title="Zoom to extent" />
                                    <input type="range" name="range" ng-model="value" min="{{0}}"
                                        max="{{100}}">
                                    <hr>
                                </span>
```

Function in the Component:

```
toogleRange($event){
    console.log('toogleRange EVENT',$event)
}
```

ng-repeat sample:

```
                <li class="display__block"
                    ng-repeat="layer in $ctrl.myLayersScope">
                 --- span code ---                
                </li>
```

Comment: Can you share full code of the template at least including `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Please check my edited post @tmhao2005

Comment: why don't you pass  item `layer` in your callback `$ctrl.toogleRange(layer)`, then you set the status for that item like: `layer.hide = true`, then set the condition on your input with `ng-if="!layer.hide"`

Comment: you need to use ng-show,  something like <li class="display__block" ng-show="layer.visible"
      ng-repeat="layer in $ctrl.myLayersScope">
 </li> and toggle the visible attribute on click

Comment: layer is a specific class type. I cannot randomly add fields to it without adding/ changing the class  properties. @tmhao2005

Comment: Or you can either create an object to store `{ [id]: [hide] }` separately or create a class which extends your Layer class also a good way to go